# Writing on a html input element with python

Tags: python, html, input

I know how to write on a input element in php with `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`
Is there any way in python to do that? I am new to python.
Say for example I have an input element with the name "Name". How will I write on it using python?

**EDIT:**

Here is the webpage: http://ooredoo.mv/edirectory
Here is my code so far

```
'payload = {
    'captcha': capData,
    'number': num
}
url = "http://ooredoo.mv/edirectory"
r = requests.post(url, data=payload)

print(r.text)'
```

I provide the capData and num earlier.
Then I am not sure how to get the data back. When I pass the two variables to the server, it returns two div with classes `edir-number` and `edir-add` .The div elements only has text inside it. So I just want to know how to retrieve that two values now.

Comment: You mean you want to use python to send HTTP Post Requests?  The `urllib` and `urllib2` libraries?  `Mechanize`?  `Requests`?  There are multiple libraries that can accomplish this for you, but you should pick one and try it out, then let us know what trouble you encounter (if any).  Just asking us to write the code for you doesn't generally go over well here.

Comment: Sure. I just wanted to know what I should do. I am new to programming too. So I didn't know there would be some kind of 'library' for that.
Anyway, thanks. I will check them out. :D